# how to update using hasmany relation table in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have created 2 tables 1 one is a subscription table and the second one is the details table...  here using the primary key of subscription table is the foreign key of details table... I using to hasmany relation to list out all data,now i want to list out the data using with primary key(id)... anyone can help me to find out a solution in lavravel?

Model named as Subscription

```
public function Sub_details()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Sub_details::class,'sub_id','id');
}
```

Controller named as SubscriptionController

```
function update_subscription($id)
{
    $sub = subscription::findOrFail($id)->with('Subcategory')->get();
    return view('admin/adm_update_subscription',["sub"=>$sub]);
}
```

Comment: First of all, you should try to follow Laravel guidelines for naming the models, have a look [here](https://webdevetc.com/blog/laravel-naming-conventions)
That is sometimes a leading issue in these kind of problems since Laravel has some magic behind, expecting certain model names

Comment: There's too many unknowns here for us to troubleshoot beyond guessing. Start of by setting your application in debug-mode, then share with us the error your receive.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the model to be `Subscription` and not sure where the `Subcategory` relationship comes from, that should be probably be `subcategory`:

```
$sub = Subscription::with('subcategory')->findOrFail($id);
```

When you are calling `with` after the find you are creating a new Builder instance and `get` is retrieving all the records.

Also most likely this method should be more like `edit_subscription` since it isn't doing any "updating" and is returning a view.